# Get Time difference between two Timestamps

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I would like to know how to get the Time difference between two Timestamps.
The two Timestamps will always be on the same Date.

I receive a negative long value as Result whereas I would like to get the Time difference in Minutes.

SQL gets me the right data, but I will attach the code a as well.

```
public long CalculateTimeFromTimestamp(Timestamp d1, Timestamp d2){
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    Date endDate = null, reqDate= null;

    try {
         endDate = sdf.parse(d1.toString());
         reqDate = sdf.parse(d2.toString());
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return endDate.getTime() - reqDate.getTime();

}

public long getArbeitszeitPerPro(int id) {
    Statement stmt = null;
    String sql = "SELECT ARBEITSBLOCK.STARTZEIT , "
                + " ARBEITSBLOCK.ENDZEIT "
                + " FROM ARBEITSBLOCK "
                + " INNER JOIN TAETIGKEIT "
                + " ON ARBEITSBLOCK.TAETIGKEIT_ID = TAETIGKEIT.ID "
                + " INNER JOIN PROJEKT "
                + " ON PROJEKT.ID = TAETIGKEIT.PROJEKT_ID "
                + " WHERE PROJEKT.ID = " + id; 


    long ergb = 0;

    try{
        stmt = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
        if(rs.last()){
            s = new Timestamp[rs.getRow()][2];
            rs.beforeFirst();
        }


        while(rs.next()){
            ergb += d.CalculateTimeFromTimestamp(rs.getTimestamp(1), rs.getTimestamp(2));

        }

    }
    catch(SQLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return ergb;    
}
```

Comment: @fge: how could converting an `int` to a character string result in an injection vulnerability?

Comment: What are  the data types of `ARBEITSBLOCK.STARTZEIT` and `ARBEITSBLOCK.ENDZEIT`?

Comment: They are dates, but I made it work with dividing the time by 1000 and *(-1). Thanks tho!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the difference in milliseconds, and divide by the number of milliseconds in a minute (60,000):

```
   public long CalculateTimeFromTimestamp(Timestamp d1, Timestamp d2){
        return Math.abs(d1.getTime() - d2.getTime()) / 60000L;
    }
```